# Applying masks to transfer pixel values to new images with Python PIL

Tags: python, comparison, python-imaging-library, pixel, mask

new to PIL and image processing with Python, probably just missing a basic function.

I am trying to apply multiple masks to one UHD image to create multiple output images showing only the pixels which each mask covers.

All images have the exact same dimensions, masks have a black area.

From my UHD source image (took a roads layer from NaturalEarth) I want to create new ones (for a sequence) showing transparency and the exact pixel value for the areas covered by the mask. Areas not covered by the mask (white) should be fully transparent.

I got it to work correctly, however, it takes forever and I want to do this for a set of more than a 1000 masks resulting in the same number of final sequence images.

Here is what I did so far:

```
from PIL import Image

imgDim = (4096, 2048)
sourceImg = Image.open('4K_roads0p05.png')
imgSeqMasks = ["gcMask_Stockholm_7400.png"]

for img in imgSeqMasks:
    blank_image = Image.new("RGBA", imgDim)
    i = Image.open(str(img))
    rgbai = i.convert('RGBA')

    if i.size == imgDim:        
        for x in range(imgDim[0]):
            for y in range(imgDim[1]):
                r, g, b, a = rgbai.getpixel((x, y))

                if (r, g, b, a) == (0, 0, 0, 255):
                    rsrc, gsrc, bsrc, asrc = sourceImg.getpixel((x, y))
                    blank_image.putpixel((x, y), (rsrc, gsrc, bsrc, asrc))
                blank_image.save('stockholmRoadsAnim_'+str(img)+'.png')
```

I obviously replaced the mask sequence folder with a single image to test it first. Here is the result if I set it to the x in range(2100, 2120) and y in range(450, 470)

[good result for area appr. Belgium/Luxembourg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTyTW.png)

[original Image (source image layer)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1irL.png)

[and one of the many mask images I used for this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dz7Hc.png)

this is just 20 by 20 pixel and it takes 109.763999939 s

Any ideas how to speed this up?

Comment: Why don't you just put the mask into the alpha layer - then you'll just see the ones you want to see and you won't see the ones you don't want to see. Or did I miss something?

Comment: Your question is quite hard to follow. Your code has some 4k roads and a list of masks with only one mask in it and that's Stockholm. Your images seem to have Belgium and the whole world and something wavy which doesn't seem to show up anywhere? I have no idea what is what. Are your images related to your code please? If so, how?

Comment: these are just file names, images are not related to the code. These roads should be replaceable by any image of the same dimensions. My masks in this case are progressive great circle areas originating from one point - in this case from Stockholm. In the end I want to stitch together the sequence files  to a video to have the roads look like expanding from Stockholm all around the world

Comment: img.putalpha() does pretty much what I wanted to achieve. <https://kite.com/python/examples/4889/PIL-mask-an-area-of-an-image-with-alpha-transparency> Here is a quick guide. Thank you @Mark Setchell for your help.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project.